# Excel to auto-remove duplicates before sum in CSV based on URL-paramter

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, xlsx, vba

I am using Really Simple Traffic Logger to store Date, Timestamp, IP and visited site by users on my website. Each user visiting the website is assigned a UID by a parameter in the URL in the form of:

```
http://www.domain.com/site.php?=dTM_c1_uid7

dTM = customer,
c1 = category 1,
uid7 = uid for person 7
```

The csv file stored contains the following:

```
"DATE","TIME","IP","LOOKING_FOR"
"2016-05-22","07:30:40","XX.XX.XX.XX","/site.php?=dTM_c1_uid7"
"2016-05-22","07:31:10","XX.XX.XX.XX","/site.php?=dTM_c1_uid7"
"2016-05-22","07:31:19","XX.XX.XX.XX","/site.php?=dTM_c1_uid8"
```

the information is stored in a CSV-file, where I am attempting to sum the results of the data, which is to be visualized by another script in real-time. However, as many of the visitors are the same people visiting the website more than once, I would like to remove these based on the UID parameter in the URL, before calculating the sum, so each count (hit) can be calculated as unique hits.

I am therefore trying to work out a formula for auto-removing duplicates that contains the "_uid7" parameter, before calculating the sum.

Is there a smart method for constructing a formula in excel that can do that automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: I have suggested a formula for processing the data in the answer submitted. I am curious to know whether I have understood your requirements properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your data starts from `A1` Please post the following formula in `B1`and fill down the `column B` with data in `column A`

```
  =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,(SEARCH("dTM_c1_",A1,1)+7),99),CHAR(34),REPT(CHAR(32),99)))
```

You will get uid7, uid8 etc which can be counted or other processing can be done.
[image: Screenshot for csv data][image: screenshot for csv data2]

**EDIT**
Based on your comments and taking `"dTM_c1_uidnn.."` string counts of occurrence is shown in the following snapshots. I have shown two snap shots out of which one hides the helper column.

[image: snapshot1] [image: snapshot2]

This is the best I could do at the moment. Column B can be filtered either with Excel native Remove Duplicates OR by a VBA routine. Finding unique values of numerical values is comparatively easy using Frequency Function But somehow after repeated attempts despite following some tutorials, I could not get the desired results for text strings. I would appreciate your feedback positive or negative. My efforts would continue to find the most optimal solution.

Comment: skkakkar, thank you for your reply. It is much appreciated. I only need to count each string once when it contains a specific UID, e.g. /site.php?=dTM_c1_uid7 should only be counted once, even though there are more than one hit. I was hoping for a formula that would check through the entire list and only count the ones with a unique UID. Is that possible? The reason is, that I need to count the dTM and _c1 based on the unique UIDs, but with more than one entry for each UID, it will mess up the statistics.

Comment: perhaps I should mention that the entire line should only be counted once with the unique UID.

Comment: @user3926924  In any case a portion of string has to extracted to count unique IDs. What represents your unique ID String . Is it uidnn or it is different data. From your sample data it appeared dTM  and c1 are common so I have chosen uid with its number which can be of any length.. This assumption is ok If dTM remains same for all enterie  and c1 also not varies. If this portion is varying and is part of a your unique ID then that portion can be extracted out for counting. Counting unique is not  major issue at all. Any appropriate formula on top of this  preliminary working will give results

Comment: @user3926924 if you can show about 7 -8 representative sample lines indicating unique ID Part of these sample strings , rest will be easy for me.

Comment: @user3926924  Around how many unique id are there in data and what is  roughly the size of data.

Comment: @user3926924  please have a look at recent edit of my answer.